# Why won't my project run in the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

For some reason, my application will install and run fine on my device, but when I try to install my application on the iPhone Simulator, I get these warnings:

```
ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore, missing required architecture i386 in file
```

And that causes a bunch of errors that just occur when those frameworks are just not present.  Errors like:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableCharacterSet", referenced from:      objc-class-ref-to-NSMutableCharacterSet in SBJsonWriter.o
```

Comment: Looks like you're somehow linking against the device libraries and not the simulator libraries. Are you using Xcode or another build method, like a Makefile?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 3.2.3 with my base SDK set to iPhoneDevice4.0

Comment: No, it doesn't actually.

Comment: hey @z43Studio  i know its very old, but still did you find any solution to it?

Comment: Actually this project was scrapped and I recreated an identical project, stealing pretty much all of the source code and it was working fine.

Answer (score 3):

The Answer is:

1) The Base SDK should be Device

2) iPhone SDK Frameworks were copied into your project directory (on disk). Open your project directory and remove any standard iPhone SDK Frameworks.

3) Clean Caches and Rebuild

Comment: Did all of that three times, still, no success.  I removed every framework and re-added it from R.Click>Add>Add Framework..., and from the iPhoneSimulator.sdk file, neither worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It was due to dragging frameworks from one project to another with the Copy option enabled.
Even though I had later de-referenced these frameworks, and added them correctly, it still gave me these errors until I had deleted the framework directories from the project.

Comment: I didn't do this to add the frameworks. I went to the Application Info from the sidebar and added them from the Linked Frameworks and Libraries option.

Answer (score 0):

It is attempting to build against the device libraries for use on the simulator. The paths should look like:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

... with `iPhoneSimulator.platform` instead of `iPhoneOS.platform`. Check your build settings, clean the project and empty the Xcode cache(Xcode>Empty Cache...).

Comment: I've changed the base SDK to iPhone Simulator 4.0, deleted and re-added every linked library, and emptied the Xcode cache and I still get the same errors, and it has not changed to `iPhoneOS.platform`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, if you use base SDK > 3.2, you should set the architecture to optimized. Which is armv7.
I'm not sure though. 
~ Natanavra.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you set iPhone Device x.x instead of iPhone Simulator x.x as the base SDK.
A similar thing hapend to me, when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a fix.  I set the base SDK to iPhone Simulator 4.0, and because it still tried to get SDKs from the iPhoneOS, I renamed `iPhoneOS.platoform` to `iPhoneOS_2.platform` so Xcode cannot access the SDKs from that platform.

Comment: But I shouldn't have to do that!  I want this to just work on both the simulator and my device!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to build on the top menu bar and press the option clean all targets

Comment: Still 255 Errors and 15 Warnings.